# Modsecurity blocks my legit POST request (403 forbidden)

Tags: nginx-config, mod-security, web-application-firewall

I'm new to modsecurity topic so I don't know where to look for cause of this problem.

I have setup modsecurity on my new nginx/1.24.0 server with default set of recommended rules: coreruleset-3.3.0 and since then my POST XHR request is being blocked.
This is a basic Laravel/Livewire form.

The headers sent and logged by modsecurity look like:

```
POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0
content-type: application/json
origin: https://example.com
referer: https://example.com/en
pragma: no-cache
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkJVTXpEK01rYTRYVFI1aGxjOE9T...
content-length: 540
accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
te: trailers
accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-dest: empty
authorization: Basic Y2Z0cmFbjpjmdG9u
host: example.com
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
```

and the logs report:

1. "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric" - but I for me "540" looks numeric!

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^\d+$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length' (Value: `540' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "127"] 
[id "920160"] 
[msg "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric"] 
[data "540"] 
[severity "2"]
```

2. "Illegal Content-Type header" - how come "application/json" is illegal?

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^[\w/.+-]+(?... against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-type' (Value: `application/json' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "915"] 
[id "920470"] 
[rev ""] 
[msg "Illegal Content-Type header"] 
[data "application/json"] 
[severity "2"]
```

3. "Invalid HTTP Request Line" - what is invalid about this: "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"?

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^(?i:(?:[a-... against variable `REQUEST_LINE' (Value: `POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "47"] 
[id "920100"] 
[msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] 
[data "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"]
```

..and then the request is blocked

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `13' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] 
[line "80"] 
[id "949110"] 
[msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 13)"] 
[data ""] 
[severity "2"]
```

So I'm totally surprised and I don't know what can I do about this since the rules seem legit but also I don't feel like breaking any of them.

The situation was tested also with a simple curl query:

```
curl -v -d '{"arg":"foo", "arg2":bar}' -H "content-length: 25" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "x-format-output: txt-matched-rules" "https://example.com/livewire/update"
```

and I'm also being 403 blocked:

```
---EdzD52pk---A--
[22/Jan/2024:12:50:45 +0000] 1705927845 127.0.0.1 57452 127.0.0.1 443
---EdzD52pk---B--
POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0
host: example.com
user-agent: curl/7.81.0
accept: */*
x-format-output: txt-matched-rules
content-length: 25
content-type: application/json


---EdzD52pk---F--
HTTP/2.0 403
Server: nginx/1.24.0
Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 12:50:45 GMT
Content-Length: 153
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

---EdzD52pk---H--
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^\d+$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length' (Value: `25' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "127"] [id "920160"] [rev ""] [msg "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric"] [data "25"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref "v114,2"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^[\w/.+-]+(?:\s?;\s?(?:action|boundary|charset|type|start(?:-info)?)\s?=\s?['\"\w.()+,/:=?<>@-]+)*$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-type' (Value: `application/json' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "915"] [id "920470"] [rev ""] [msg "Illegal Content-Type header"] [data "application/json"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/255/153"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref "v131,16t:lowercase"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^(?i:(?:[a-z]{3,10}\s+(?:\w{3,7}?://[\w\-\./]*(?::\d+)?)?/[^?#]*(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[\S]*)?|connect (?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\.?(?::\d+)?|options \*)\s+[\w\./]+|get /[^?#]*(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[\S]*)?)$' against variable `REQUEST_LINE' (Value: `POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "47"] [id "920100"] [rev ""] [msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] [data "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"] [severity "4"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref "v0,30"]
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `13' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "80"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 13)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

CRS Dev-on-duty here. I see you've repeated the question from last week in SE. Anyways, there had been similar reports to your problem last year or so, and they were due to unofficial Nginx installations. You can read more [here](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues/3117#issuecomment-1419548808).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the duplication but I couldn't find help on SE. Thanks for the link - I will follow that thread. Although my nginx was from an official source like: `sudo apt update` + `sudo apt install nginx` running on Ubuntu  22.04 64 bit UEFI Edition.

Comment: No problem. The official package provided by Ubuntu 22.04.3 is 1.18. You're running 1.24.